# Firebase Glide not displaying image

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

Searched many sites and I haven't yet found the answer.

The image isn't  being uploaded from Firebase and I honestly don't know what it could be.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
spaceRef = storageRef.child("Users/" + user.getEmail().toString() + "/images/Countries/Spain" /*+ chosenCountry*/);

            Glide.with(ActPhotoViewing.this.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(spaceRef)
                    .into(showImg);
```

Implementations in .gradle

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
```

Comment: try to access your image from your browser first...to ensure its already live

Comment: It is, something must be wrong with the code. Could you see something wrong?

Comment: spaceRef its hold the path be sure the path is correct by visit it in browser if not then the problem from code

Comment: also see logcat if any error msg post it

Comment: Use `getDownloadUrl()` method to get uri and pass that uri in `Glide.load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using FirebaseUI you need to use the generated API.  When you build your project it should generate a GlideApp class that you will use in place of your Glide static calls.

Try:

```
    GlideApp.with(ActPhotoViewing.this.getApplicationContext())
            .load(spaceRef)
            .into(showImg);
```

If you are getting errors that GlideApp is not found make sure you are following the instructions here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage.  Then clean/rebuild your project.